# How do I implement a bluetooth scanner that obtains the advertising data from my Ibeacons?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, rxandroidble

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/neXenio/BLE-Indoor-Positioning) repo that uses [this](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) library for Bluetooth scanning on Android. Here is the scanning Method here. Currently, it's not picking up my IBeacons and it explains in the Repo why that is, however, I'm not sure where to go from here in this method and how to make it scan for my Beacons.

```
public static void startScanning() {
    if (isScanning()) {
        return;
    }

    final BluetoothClient instance = getInstance();
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting to scan for beacons");

    ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            .build();

    instance.scanningSubscription = instance.rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(scanSettings)
            .subscribe(new Observer<ScanResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth scanning error", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ScanResult scanResult) {
                    instance.processScanResult(scanResult);
                }
            });
}
```

These are the modifications I made in this method.

```
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                .build();
        ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                .setServiceUuid(UUID).build();

        instance.scanningSubscription = instance.rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(scanSettings, scanFilter)
                .subscribe(new Observer<ScanResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth scanning error", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ScanResult scanResult) {
                        instance.processScanResult(scanResult);
                    }
                });
```

As you can see I added a ScanFilter so it can find the UUID for my IBeacons and obtain the advertising data from them (which I then send to the process scan result method). But this implementation doesn't work, since it won't allow me to outright filter a UUID.

I'm not sure if what I'm doing here is right, I've read the RxAndroidBle library repo readme but there isn't a lot to go on it and I can't get the app to scan for my specific Beacons. I have 4 IBeacons which are setup around my home, each Ibeacon I have has a UUID of "EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524".

How would I be able to get this method to correctly scan for that specific UUID or just wrap around the IBeacon's API's so I can obtain the necessary advertising data as the repo intends? I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing it correctly but I think I've got the right idea, any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

When using a ScanFilter on Android, the supplied UUID is a GATT Service UUID which is not the same thing at all as an iBeacon UUID, despite the fact that all 128-bit UUIDs look superficially similar when expressed as a String.

Short answer:  stop using that UUID in your scan filter.  If you must use a scan filter for some reason, use an empty one e.g. (`ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().build();`).

One caveat:  empty scan filters will not allow you to scan with the screen off on Samsung devices.  The only alternative is to build an iBeacon-specific scan filter which is more complex.  Before you bother to do that, make sure you even need to.

Comment: Thank you for that, I've obviously got confused on the UUID part and thought they were the same thing